# Share the love buttons on stackexchange.com/performance don't work

Tags: bug, status-completed

On the [bottom of the page](https://stackexchange.com/performance) the buttons to share on Twitter and Facebook do nothing.

> [image]

Comment: @Anna why did Shog delete the first bug report about this page? If it is a secret page, better just hide it instead of letting us waste time finding its bugs.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have no idea. Ask Shog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, we removed them for the time being.

This page isn’t secret (it has a public URL, after all) but is not something we are promoting much. We’re playing with designs and working to wire up real-time-ish numbers.